# What's wrong with this sentence? ("which should have made" vs. "making")

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Hiram Bingham first crossed the Andes Mountains in February 1909, the wettest month of the year, which should have made his travels difficult.

Apparently, the correct sentence is:

> Hiram Bingham first crossed the Andes Mountains in February 1909, the wettest month of the year, making his travels difficult.

Comment: Who says the first is wrong?  He crossed by ornithopter, so the wetness didn't really bother him.

Comment: Suppose that instead of commas, we used parentheses to set of the "the wettest month of the year." That would give us this: "Hiram Bingham first crossed the Andes Mountains in February 1909 (the wettest month of the year), which should have made his travels difficult." It seems to me that the sense of the sentence is "Hiram Bingham first crossed the Andes Mountains in February 1909, which should have made his travels difficult" with an added parenthetical about why February was a particularly problematic month for travel. Since commas are interchangeable with parentheses for setting off...

Comment: ...a parenthetical, it seems to me that the original sentence can be read in exactly the same way as the version with parentheses. And since there is nothing wrong with the version with parentheses, the assertion that the original sentence is incorrect in some fundamental way seems to me to be false. Is there more context to the assignment, such as a description of the basis upon which you are supposed to determine that one version is better than the other?

Comment: Dropping the parenthetical from the second sentence leaves 'Hiram Bingham first crossed the Andes Mountains in February 1909,  making his travels difficult.' Though I'd agree that it's silly to claim that the use of misplaced modifiers is always scandalous, I'd say that  'I made my travels difficult' sounds unidiomatic and so I'd avoid this rendering. I'd probably use 'Hiram Bingham first crossed the Andes Mountains (in 1909) in February – the wettest month of the year, which should have made his travels difficult.'

Answer (score 1):

It might be a matter of voice and presentation. Sentence 1 is **speculative**, and Sentence 2 is **informative**. It might not be grammatically incorrect, but it would be sub-optimal if the point of the sentence is to inform and not to give opinion.

> Hiram Bingham first crossed the Andes Mountains in February 1909, the wettest month of the year, which should have made his travels difficult.

Here, a **speculation** is being made that the fact that February in 1909 was the wettest month of that year was the reason that his travels **might** have been difficult. However, this is not presented as a **fact**.

> Hiram Bingham first crossed the Andes Mountains in February 1909, the wettest month of the year, making his travels difficult.

Here, a **statement** or **conclusion** is being made that February 1909 being the wettest month of the year was **absolutely** the reason that his travels were difficult.

Whether the information is true or not, I don't know, but this is the only flaw I see with this pair of sentences.

Comment: I'd really like a justification for that down-vote.

Comment: Well I am going to vote it up so there you go. I can see a very weak argument for a down vote, namely in that a sentence that does not mean what the person uttering it intends is way lower than sub-optimal. It is plain wrong. But I think what you intended was that such a sentence may be grammatical in form but will be incorrect.

Comment: But psosuna noted "if" the point of the sentence is to inform and not to give opinion. But "if" the point of the sentence is to give opinion and not inform, the sentence is fine. .

Comment: @zan I think you misunderstood my point. I was not at all disagreeing that the various sentences are grammatical. But the hypothesis was that the purpose was to inform, in which case the clause used fails, and therefore "suboptimal" is not well chosen. That is a valid criticism, but, in my opinion, it is too minor to warrant a down vote on what was a cogent, helpful, and generally correct answer.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Whose hypothesis?

Comment: @Zan You wrote "But psosuna noted 'if'" in your first comment. A clause starting with "if" presents a hypothesis, something that is to be accepted as true for purposes of argument. So the hypothesis that you referenced was that of the OP. My comment was based on accepting that hypothesis, not denying it. I must admit that it is not clear to me what you object to in either my answer or my comments. I shall address it or correct it if you are so kind as to be explicit in your objection.

Comment: @jeffMorrow Your contention is that  " If the sentence is meant to inform," then "Hiram Bingham first crossed the Andes Mountains in February 1909, the wettest month of the year, which should have made his travels difficult." is wrong. That sentence informs me that: 1.  Hiram Bingham first crossed the Andes Mountains in February 1909, 2. February is the wettest month of the year, 3. the author believes that the conditions "should have made the trip difficult."  Two pieces of information, one opinion. Does that make the sentence wrong?

Comment: @ Zan. But I never said the sentence was wrong. I was fundamentally agreeing with the original answer. However, if your position is that the sentence is informative because it intended only to give the speaker's opinion and make no assertion about the actual event, I agree. If, however, the intent of the sentence that was the initial subject of discussion was to make an informative assertion about the actual event, then the form of that sentence was incorrect, exactly as the original answer specified.

Comment: @JeffMorrow --  chiming in. What Zan is referring to is the reason why I chose the word "sub-optimal" for describing the sentence. Both sentences contain facts and are informative, but only one is speculative. The variance in the first example gives a speculation at the end instead of another fact. So, while it conveys facts, it also conveys an opinion, making it "sub-optimal." It's not 100% wrong but it certainly isn't 100% right either in that regard --  it's grammatically sound, it presents facts, but an opinion has no place in a piece that is meant to inform with hard facts.

Comment: @ psosuna I am tiring of an argument where I have been basically agreeing with you and getting a lot of guff for doing so. If something has "no place," then "sub-optimal" is not a good description. As, however, I have now tried to say several times, I thought that was a minor flaw in a good answer. As they say, no kind deed goes unpunished.

Comment: @JeffMorrow --  I'm not disagreeing with you in the least. Just literally *chiming in*. I think you're looking at it from a black and white perspective. I'm looking at it as 2/3 isn't half bad but not optimal. Anyway, I'm not giving anyone any guff. Just wanting to get all involved on the same page because we can all agree that example 1 is not the best choice given that context, regardless of degree of correctness or lack thereof, as a choice between example 1 and 2. Fair enough?

Comment: @psosuna Somehow I got a new message alert for this. At any rate, I'm glad I checked back. We see "sub-optimal" the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The clause "which should have made his travels difficult" suggests that his travels were not difficult without explicitly affirming that possibility.

The clause "which might have made his travels difficult" suggests that whether his travels were difficult is not known to the speaker or writer.

The clause " which made his travels difficult" explicitly affirms that his travels were difficult.

Thus, the first two are speculative; the third is informative.

All are grammatical. Each differs in meaning.